# PHP won't escape HTML special characters

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2, html-escape-characters

In a ZF2 application, I have a `.phtml` layout containing the following:

```
<p>Created in 2015 <?php echo htmlspecialchars("by Jérôme Verstrynge",ENT_HTML5); ?></p>
```

Yet, when I check the source of returned pages, I get:

```
<p>Created in 2015 by Jérôme Verstrynge</p>
```

instead of

```
<p>Created in 2015 by J&eacute;r&ocirc;me Verstrynge</p>
```

Why?

Comment: Those aren't 'special' characters according to PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php Only `&<>'"`, and the quotes only when set..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the manual](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars), `htmlspecialchars()` only translates `&`, `"`, `'`, `<` and `>`. I think you are confusing it with `htmlentities()`.

ZF2 also has an escaper view helper with a lot more options: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.escaper.escaping-html.html